# Running vb.net programs under osx

Tags: vb.net, macos, clickonce

I developed a time recording software with vb.net. To run the program the client pc must have .net 4.5 installed. Now one person has an apple laptop with mac os and i dont know how to run the program there. Is it possible to install .net 4.5 on macos? My research suggested Mono but only with .net 3.5. Another point is the update ClickOnce procedure. Even if i get the program to work is it possible that ClickOnce works?

Comment: Most .Net 4.5 features should be avaiable in Mono. Have you tried running your application on Mono? Or used the [Mono Migration Analyzer](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA)?

Comment: I havent tried yet since it is not my pc and i dont want to install (maybe experimental) software on it. Mono Migration Analysier is a good hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Parallels for Mac. It's let you host a virtual machine on you Mac and then they can run any windows apps they need. Works like a charm.

As for Click-Once, it will work and push the install to the Mac, but will not update correctly when running under Parallels. I haven't found a good work-around for it yet besides using something Like WiX instead of Click-Once.